# how to replace synchronous local-storage with asynchronous Indexed-db for Angular App

Tags: angular, local-storage, indexeddb

I am using local storage to get data and if data is not available on local storage then making server API call and and adding data to storage for future use then returning data. so next time it will return data from storage rather than from API Call.

I have generic function to do this work and everything works fine.

```
 getData(host,url):Observable<any> {
    const serverurl = host + url;
    const apiname = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? url.substring(1, url.indexOf('?')) : url.substring(1, url.length);
    const params = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1, url.length) : '';
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var result = null ;
    result = this.GetStorageEx(apiname, params);
    if (result) 
    {
      var t1 = performance.now()
      console.log(apiname + ' returned from storage. time taken:' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
      return new Observable(observer => {observer.next(result);observer.complete();})
    } 
    else 
    {
       return this.getDataFromServer(serverurl).pipe(map(
        result => {
          this.UpdateStorageEx(apiname,result, params);
          var t1 = performance.now()
          console.log(apiname + ' returned from server. time taken:' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
          return result;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
     ));
   }
  }
```

Here GetStorageEx is synchronous call so I am able to call server API if result is null.

Due to limitations on local storage in terms of data size, I decided to use IndexedDB, but I see its asynchronous call to get data.

So my question is how should I modify function getData in such way that caller of this function need not to change and behaviour of this fuction will remains same. Only expected change is instead of GetStorageEx to get from local storage , I need to get it from IndexedDB. (getData from IndexedDB returns promise).

Comment: 2 things first: 1) Use `of(result)` when you want to create an observable from a synchronous data. 2) seems strange to use a `map` operator when you return the exact same object. You should use `tap` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to chain observables using RxJs:

```
 getData(host,url):Observable<any> {
    // stuff
    var t0 = performance.now();
    this.GetDataFromDb(...).pipe(
        switchMap(dbData => {
          if(dbData && dbData.length > 0) {
            // data found in DB, return it ("of" trick to have the same behavior as the else statement)
            return of(dbData)
          } else {
            // no data in DB, let's call the server
            // switch from DB observable to Server observable
            return this.getDataFromServer(serverurl).pipe(
                           tap(serverData => {
                             this.UpdateDbEx(apiname,result, params).subscribe(); // empty subscribe if writing in DB is async
                             var t1 = performance.now()
                             console.log(apiname + ' returned from server. time taken:' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
                           })
                         );
          }
        })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it perfectly works. Do you know what is good resource to learn about RxJs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But google must have a lot of tutorials about it, since it is a widely used library in Angular.